# When to call the backend and when to store locally (angularjs)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parse-platform, server

I have an ionic app and a Parse.com backend. My users can perform CRUD functions on exercise programmes, changing every aspect of the programme including adding, deleting, editing the exercises within it.

I am confused about when to save, when to call the server and how much data can be held in services / `$rootScope`?

Typical user flow is as below:

1. Create Programme and Client (Create both on server and store data in `$localStorage`).
2. User goes to edit screen where they can perform CRUD functions on all exercises within the programme. Currently I perform a server call on each function so it is synced to the backed.
3. The user may go back and select a different programme - downloading the data and storing it localStorage again.

My question is how can I ensure that my users data is always saved to the server and offer them a responsive fast user experience.

Would it be normal to have a timeout function that triggers a save periodically? On a mobile the amount of calls to the server is quite painful over a poor connection.

Any ideas on full local / remote sync with Ionic and Parse.com would be welcome.

Comment: How about callbacks?

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, the best way to think of this is as follows:

- `localStorage` is essentially a cache layer, which if up to date is great because it can reduce network calls. However it is limited to the current session, and should be treated as volatile storage.
- Your server is your source of truth, and as such, should always be updated.

What this means is, for reads, localstorage is great, you don't need to fetch your data a million times if it hasn't changed. For writes, always trust your server for long term storage.

The pattern I suggest is, on load, fetch any relevant data and save it to local storage. Any further reads should come from local storage. Edits, should go directly to the server, and on success, you can write those changes to localstorage. This way, if you have an error on save, the user can be informed, and/or you can use localstorage as a queue to continue trying to post the data to the server until a full success.

Answer (score 1):

This is called "offline sync" or sometimes "4 ways data binding". The point is to cache data locally and sync it with a remote backend. This is a very common need, but the solutions are unfornately not that common... The ideal flow would follows this philosophy:

- **save** data locally
- try to **sync** it with server (performing auto **merges**)

And

- **Periodically sync**, along with a timer and maybe some "connection resumed" event

This is very hard to achieve manually. If been searching modules for a long time, and the only ones that come to my mind don't realy fit your needs (become they often are backend providers that give you frontend connectors; and you already have an opiniated backend), but here they are anyway:

- Strongloop's [Loopback.io](http://docs.strongloop.com/plugins/servlet/mobile#content/view/3836343)
- [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com)
- [PouchDB](http://pouchdb.com)